# JAVA Sub Enum declaration

Tags: java, enums

I want to  access  an enum value from another enum declaration in code as shown below . But i could not achive to declare it ,is there any way to do this in java.

**`LOOK_UP.BACKOFFICE_DEAFULT_RAPOR_DATE.LAST_FINISHED_MSPOT_TRADING_DATE`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## New material to address OP's comment to ignore code

If you have two `enums`, `OuterEnum` and `InnerEnum`, and `OuterEnum` has a field of type `InnerEnum`, you can kind of do what you're talking about. Simplifying drastically, ...

```
enum OuterEnum {
    OUTER1(InnerEnum.INNER1), OUTER2(InnerEnum.INNER2);
    public final InnerEnum myInner;
    private OuterEnum(InnerEnum inner) {
        this.myInner = inner;
    }
}

enum InnerEnum {
    INNER1, INNER2;
}
```

Now you can say `OuterEnum.OUTER1.myInner` or `OuterEnum.OUTER2.myInner` to get the `InnerEnum` value held by the `OuterEnum`. But you can't say something like `OuterEnum.OUTER1.INNER1`. That just doesn't make any sense. If you know you want `INNER1` you should just say `InnerEnum.INNER1`.

You can make `InnerEnum` a true inner `enum` by declaring it within `OuterEnum`, but the same principles apply. If you know the precise value you want, just reference it directly. If you want to know the value held by another `enum`, reference it indirectly as above.

## Previous contents of answer to address OP's code

You seem to have inverted your enums. The first one must be the containing enum. To do it in the way you've stated, you'd need to do something like this:

```
public enum LOOK_UP {
    BACKOFFICE_DEAFULT_RAPOR_DATE("BACKOFFICE_DEAFULT_RAPOR_DATE", LOOK_UP_OPTION.LAST_FINISHED_MSPOT_TRADING_DATE),
    BACKOFFICE_QUERY_TYPE("BACKOFFICE_QUERY_TYPE", LOOK_UP_OPTION.STATIC_QUERY_TYPE);
    private String name;
    public final LOOK_UP_OPTION option;
    private LOOK_UP(String name, LOOK_UP_OPTION option){
        this.name=name;
        this.option = option;
    }

     public String getName(){
         return  name;
    }

    public enum LOOK_UP_OPTION {
        LAST_FINISHED_MSPOT_TRADING_DATE(LOOK_UP.BACKOFFICE_DEAFULT_RAPOR_DATE ,"LAST_FINISHED_MSPOT_TRADING_DATE","LAST FINISHED MSPOT TRADING DATE"),
        STATIC_QUERY_TYPE(LOOK_UP.BACKOFFICE_QUERY_TYPE ,"STATIC_QUERY_TYPE","Static Query");

        LOOK_UP look_up;
        private String code;
        private String  label;

        //db miss match label and code
        private LOOK_UP_OPTION(LOOK_UP look_up , String code,String label){
            this.look_up=look_up;
            this.code=code;
            this.label=label;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can invoke, say, 
    LOOK_UP.BACKOFFICE_DEAFULT_RAPOR_DATE.LOOK_UP_OPTION;
and you'd get the `LAST_FINISHED_MSPOT_TRADING_DATE` value.

The `LOOK_UP_OPTION` attribute of `LOOK_UP` needs to be final to prevent code from changing it.

Comment: Forget about my code i could not state it clearly.I am wondering if is possible to  declare something like below and using it at compile time. , FIRST_ENUM_DECLARATION.AN_OPTION_OF_FIRST_DECLARATION.INNER_ENUM_DECLARATION;

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
BACKOFFICE_DEAFULT_RAPOR_DATE("BACKOFFICE_DEAFULT_RAPOR_DATE"); 
BACKOFFICE_QUERY_TYPE("BACKOFFICE_QUERY_TYPE"),
```

to

```
BACKOFFICE_DEAFULT_RAPOR_DATE("BACKOFFICE_DEAFULT_RAPOR_DATE"), // <--- comma
BACKOFFICE_QUERY_TYPE("BACKOFFICE_QUERY_TYPE"); // <--- semi colon
...

} // <--- missing closing curly brace at the end
```

Full code:

```
public enum LOOK_UP {
    BACKOFFICE_DEAFULT_RAPOR_DATE("BACKOFFICE_DEAFULT_RAPOR_DATE"), // <--- (1)
    BACKOFFICE_QUERY_TYPE("BACKOFFICE_QUERY_TYPE"); // <--- (2)

    // no changes

    public enum LOOK_UP_OPTION {
        // no changes
    }
} // <--- (3)
```

Comment: I shorten the enum declaration  when sending question sorry for miss typing But My question still valide.

Comment: Do you still encounter a problem ?

Comment: Yes ,I want to know how i can declare  something like below .An enumn containig another enum and accessed at compile time .LOOK_UP.BACKOFFICE_DEAFULT_RAPOR_DATE.LAST_FINISHED_MSPOT_TRADING_DATE

Comment: @ayengin you can't do that *this way*. **BACKOFFICE_DEAFULT_RAPOR_DATE.LAST_FINISHED_MSPOT_TRADING_DATE** ha no meaning.

Comment: Forget about my code i could not state it clearly.I am wondering if is possible to  declare something like below and using it at compile time. , FIRST_ENUM_DECLARATION.AN_OPTION_OF_FIRST_DECLARATION.INNER_ENUM_DECLARATION;